# How to add discount codes to the sabre bargain finder rest api request

Tags: rest, api, sabre

How to add a corporate discount (up front discount) to the bargain finder rest api request?

OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Corporate codes can be added in the following path

OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.TravelPreferences.TPA_Extensions.FlexibleFares.FareParameters.CorporateID.Code

BFM documentation can be found here: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. This could be helpful to anyone:

"FlexibleFares" : {
 "FareParameters":
    [{
       "CorporateID":
       [{
         "Code":"GAVXX"}
       ]}}